# Is there any way to disable flyway SQL migration from the transaction

Tags: sql-server, flyway

I'm trying to execute the Flyway migration to drop fulltext index but it could not be run inside the migration:

```
DROP FULLTEXT INDEX ON BusinessEntity
```

It throws an error:

> Message: DROP FULLTEXT INDEX statement cannot be used inside a user transaction.

As I understand from the [documentation](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq#rollback):

> Flyway runs each migration in a separate transaction.

I am interesting is there any way to run SQL code outside the migration or somehow turn it off for certain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has already [been fixed](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2071) in the Flyway master branch but is not yet in a release.

The next version, [5.2.0](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/milestone/18), should resolve it.

In the meantime, you could [build it from source](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/contribute/code/setup) yourself.

### Update 2019-01-03

Version 5.2.0 was released a while back.

I have created a [repository](https://github.com/andyrbell/flyway-sql-server-fulltext-index) to replicate the error using Flyway 5.1.4 - or at least it fails on `CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX` because of the same underlying problem. Changing the version to 5.2.0 fixes the problem, as expected.

Comment: Is there a workaround how could I use this on prod env without custom jar at this point?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. There is no mention of a way to skip transactions in the [documentation](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#transactions). I had a quick look at the [code](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/17bbefca6b010f7297598996d8f64421d2056b80/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/database/sqlserver/SQLServerSqlStatementBuilder.java#L64-L69) but I can't see a way to override it without a code change. Sorry.

Comment: hey, I am still facing this issue even after upgrading to 5.2.0 (it is running with springboot application) - do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @user1002065 Not sure. Does it fail with the same exception? I have replicated the error with 5.1.4 and then switched to 5.2.0 which fixed it, as expected. Is Spring Boot definitely using the correct version of Flyway? Is Flyway throwing an exception because of the previously failed migration..?

Comment: This issue is ocurring in 6.0.8 Community for SQL Server when calling sys.sp_grantdbaccess.