# How to disable transactions for individual migrations in Flyway on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, flyway

I have a Flyway migration that is failing in Flyway Community Edition 6.0.8 with the following error:

```
The procedure 'sys.sp_grantdbaccess' cannot be executed within a transaction.
```

My original migration script is:

```
EXEC sp_grantdbaccess 'foo', 'bar'
```

I attempted to run it as dynamic SQL but ran into the same issue:

```
exec('EXEC sp_grantdbaccess N''foo'', N''bar''')
```

I have also tried the -mixed=true option on the flyway migrate command line to allow transactional and non-trnsactional migrations to run but I am receiving the same error.

Can transactions be disabled on a per-migration basis?  Or even for an entire "migrate" operation?  If neither of those are options, is there a way within the migration script itself to effect the change in question without running into the transaction restriction?

This is not a duplicate of [Is there any way to disable flyway SQL migration from the transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52332529/is-there-any-way-to-disable-flyway-sql-migration-from-the-transaction) for several reasons:

1. The error occurs for a different SQL operation.
2. The behavior in question appears to have been resolved in an earlier release of Flyway, but is still occurring for this operation.

Comment: Not sure about FlyAway or the context here so I may be way off....but could you not set the transaction isolation level?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ability to configure individual scripts to (not) run in a transaction has been added in Flyway 6.1, released this week: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#manual-override

Comment: the link is now broken but this link shows the feature: https://flywaydb.org/blog/flyway-6-1-0 see `Manual transaction override` title on the page.